# SimpleExoPlayer doesn't stream for the second time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I want to play a radio channel from url by using SimpleExoPlayer, the code works only for the first time, i.e., when I press play it works, then I press again it stops. But if I press again play button it doesn't play.
I tried to delete cache in every stop event but it also didn't solve the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String source;
private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
private boolean isPlaying;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.image_play);
    source = "http://mp3stream7.apasf.apa.at/stream/1/";
    isPlaying = false;

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isPlaying) {
                setupPlayer();
                simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlaying = true;
            } else {
                simpleExoPlayer.stop();
                simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

private void setupPlayer() {

    DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(MainActivity.this, null,
            DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF);

    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector);

    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, "Play Audio");
    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(source),
            new CacheDataSourceFactory(MainActivity.this, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 5 * 1024 * 1024),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

}

private void release_player() {
    simpleExoPlayer.release();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    simpleExoPlayer.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    simpleExoPlayer.release();
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String source;
private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlaye = null;
private boolean isPlaying;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.image_play);
    source = "http://mp3stream7.apasf.apa.at/stream/1/";
    isPlaying = false;

    //add this
    setupPlayer();

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isPlaying) {
                //remove setupPlayer(); from here
                simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                isPlaying = true;
            } else {
                //remove  simpleExoPlayer.stop(); from here
                simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(isPlaying);
    } else {
        setupPlayer();
    }

}


private void setupPlayer() {

    if (simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        simpleExoPlayer.stop();
    }
    DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(MainActivity.this, null,
            DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF);

    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector);

    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(MainActivity.this, "Play Audio");
    ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(source),
            new CacheDataSourceFactory(MainActivity.this, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 5 * 1024 * 1024),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //remove releaze from onDestroy and onPause
    simpleExoPlayer.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```